# selectively combining data across columns sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 5 columns. The feature of the data is that all values in a row are the same...but there are not always a value in each column. An example is

```
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5
1  1        1
   2  2     2 
4        4  4
8     8     
21 21
```

I would like to create a single column that list the unique numbers that are in each row. eg. the output would be:

```
output
1
2
4
8
21
```

How could I do this?

Comment: What if you have different numbers in one row, e.g. `1, 2, 3`?

Comment: Very ambiguous question.

Comment: sorry - I will try and clarify further

Answer (score 2):

Check for [**GREATEST()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) conditional expression which returns single largest value for bunch of columns for each row

```
SELECT GREATEST(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5)
FROM tableName
```

Ofcourse , you can also use **LEAST()** for smallest value.

**NULL** values are ignored and if all columns in expression for a row are **NULL** then **NULL** is returned.

Comment: The documentation says Null value are ignored so this will work if any of the column has non null value.. same for coalesce() function

Comment: . . Oops.  Postgres usually follows the SQL standard on such things, and it doesn't in this case.  So this answer will work in Postgres.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are not standard SQL. At least, [the manual says so](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST): `Note that GREATEST and LEAST are not in the SQL standard, but are a common extension. Some other databases make them return NULL if any argument is NULL, rather than only when all are NULL.` Ignoring NULL (just like most aggregate functions) seems more useful anyway.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: What standard? AIUI, `GREATEST` and `LEAST` aren't standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
coalesce(h1,coalesce(h2,coalesce(h3,coalesce(h4,h5))))
from your_tab
order by 1
```

EDIT:

The `distinct` is superfluous and only one `coalesce()` is needed:

```
select coalesce(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5)
from your_tab
order by 1 ;
```

Comment: Can't we use like this ?: coalesce(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5)